# Glitch with login function

Tags: database, authentication, delphi

I have a bit of a problem with my program's login function. The function takes input from 2 TEdits from the login form (with each being for the Username and Password respectively) then compares the input to the records within the database it's supposed to read from (I use a separate class for this). The problem is whenever there's more than 1 record in the DB or when a new record was added, it just reads a random record in the DB and then logs in after trying 2 or 3 previous times to log in and failing each time. But when there's only one record in the DB, I can log in just fine? What am I doing wrong?

**Code I'm using:**

**Class' code**

```
unit LoginCheckClass;

interface

uses
Math,SysUtils,dmLoginCheck_u;

type
TLogChk = class(TObject)

private
  fPass,fUser:string;
public
  function checkCredentials:boolean;
  constructor Create(pPass:string;pUser:string);
end;

implementation

constructor TLogChk.Create(pPass: string; pUser: string);
begin
  fPass:=pPass;
  fUser:=pUser;
end;

function TLogChk.checkCredentials:boolean;
begin
  with dmLoginCheck do
  begin
    tblLogins.First;
    while NOT tblLogins.Eof do
    begin
      if (tblLogins['Username'] = fUser) AND (tblLogins['Password'] = fPass) then
      begin
      Result:=True;
      end
      else
      begin
      Result:=False;
      end;
    tblLogins.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**Code on the form**

```
procedure TfrmStartForm.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sUsername,sPassword:string;
  bTrue:boolean;
  notGranted,Granted:integer;
begin
  //Button that checks credentials and gives the user access to the app if allowed
  sPassword:=edtPassword.Text;
  sUsername:=edtUsername.Text;
    try
       objLogChk:=TLogChk.Create(sPassword,sUsername);
        bTrue:=objLogChk.checkCredentials;
        if bTrue = True then
        begin
          Granted:=MessageDlg('Access granted',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
            if Granted = mrOK then
            begin
            frmPuntehou.ShowModal;
            frmStartForm.CloseModal;
            end;
        end
        else
        begin
          notGranted:=MessageDlg('Access denied.',mtError,[mbOK],0);
          if notGranted = mrOK then
          begin
            ResetDialog;
          end;
        end;
    finally
    objLogChk.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: There are several problems with this code. Just to mention one: `objLogChk:=TLogChk.Create(sPassword,sUsername);` must be the line immediately *BEFORE* `try` (not AFTER).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Ok, will do. What else is wrong with my code?

Comment: `if Granted = mrOk then`. This means that different things happen depending on *how* the user dismisses the single-button message box! (Clicking the OK button, clicking the red cross, pressing Enter, pressing Escape, using the "Close" system menu item (Alt+Space or title bar right click), or pressing Alt+F4.) That's *extremely* confusing! Further: Don't write `if A = True then`; write `if A then`. More: Don't write `if A then B := True else B := False`; write `B := A`. There are also strange ownership issues and global variables, it seems.

Comment: And the logic in `checkCredentials` seems strange, but I don't know what the SQL query is...

Comment: The real problem is that you process every record of the table. Don't do that. Execute an SQL query with a `WHERE` clause to retrieve *only* the record corresponding to the user (or no record if the user is not found).

Comment: Although @Olivier gave you the right solution, the explanation for your behaviour is that the `while` loop will continue with other rows which will set (overwrite) `Result` to `False` before the function returns, unless you are very lucky and get the desired row last by chance! Try to add `Exit` or `Break` after `Result := True` to see how it works. (Also, a different bug: notice that the returned value of `TLogChk.checkCredentials` might be undefined if no rows are returned. That's always a bug, and I suspect the compiler warns you about it.) You could have discovered this by yourself if ...

Comment: ...you had run the program one line at a time in the debugger.

Comment: You code seems to use a TTable (TAdoTable, TDTable, or similar). This is not the best component altough it might work. You should use a Query component (TAdoQuesy, TFDQuery and similar) using an exact SQL request such as: Query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT count(*) WHERE Username=%UserName and Password=%Password'; Query.ParamByName('Username').Value := Username; Query.ParamByName('Password').Value := Password; Query.Open; if Query.Eof then ShowMessage('Invalid login'); The exact syntax depends on the component set you use and you didn't say.

Comment: @fpiette I use a single ADO Table component for my DB connection

Comment: @Olivier Ok thx, will look into it

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Ok, I'll try all of those and let you know if everything works. I'm new to the debugging thing (we didn't really do it in school, so I'm not used to the debugging thing). Thx again

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand the ```break``` worked. Will post answer shortly

Comment: @PrimeBeat Debugging is as simple as putting a few `ShowMessage()` here and there.

Comment: Over the years there have been a number of users who posted a series of questions on SO about the problems they encounter when trying to code a log-in form like yours, including how to match the user's credentials against a table of users.  So, with respect, I think you should possibly spend a bit more time researching solutions to the problems you are encountering before posting your q here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function TLogChk.checkCredentials:boolean;
begin
Result:=False;
  with dmLoginCheck do
  begin
    tblLogins.First;
    while NOT tblLogins.Eof do
    begin
      if (tblLogins['Username'] = fUser) AND (tblLogins['Password'] = fPass) then
      begin
      Result:=True;
      Break;
      end;
    tblLogins.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why going thru all rows of a database table when SQL already offers a `WHERE` filter that could be used to only get rows where the columns "Username" and "Password" match?